# Show battery level of connected bluetooth device [Kotlin]

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth, batterylevel

Is it possible to show the battery level of a connected bluetooth device? I'm making an app that monitors devices and it connects thru bluetooth. I know how to show current batterylevel of the monitor (in this case a tablet), but I'm not sure if it's possible to see other battery levels. If anyone has idea's, please comment! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin

```
try {
    val headsetBatteryLevel = connectedHeadset.javaClass.getMethod("getBatteryLevel").invoke(connectedHeadset) as Int
    writeToLog("Battery level $headsetBatteryLevel%")
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    writeToLog("Failed to obtain battery level")
}
```

Comment: What is connectedHeadset ? can you please specify some about the same.

Comment: @BhavinSolanki the above code is inserted when I first check connected Bluetooth speakers. You can find the code in the Work Around under Question 2 here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72750231/android-wear-watches-reported-as-connected-bluetooth-headsets