# Android : Wear Watches reported as connected Bluetooth headsets?

Tags: android, bluetooth

My countdown App uses text-to-speech to provide an audio countdown.

When the app detects a Bluetooth speaker audio is sent to that speaker.

The problem Wearables like the Samsung Watch 4 and TicWatch Pro 3 are reported as HEADSETs !

e.g. My original onCreate() included:

```
// Check if a speaker is connected 
if (bluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED) 
    sendSpeechToSpeaker()
else 
    sendSpeechToPhone()
```

**Question 1**
Is there a simple fix to the above which will only detect connected HEADSETs ?

My workaround involves individually checking each connected Bluetooth device and ignoring those which are not Headsets

**Question 2**
Can someone suggest an easier method than my Workaround?

*Workaround*

During initialisation each CONNECTED Bluetooth device is checked and if they are actually a headset audio is rerouted

The btServiceListener which checks each CONNECTED device

```
val btServiceListener: ServiceListener = object : ServiceListener {
    // used to scan all CONNECTED Bluetooth devices looking for external speakers ...
    override fun onServiceConnected(profile: Int, proxy: BluetoothProfile) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            val connectionStates = intArrayOf(BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) 
            // get all connected headsets
            val connectedHeadsetList = proxy.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(connectionStates)
            for (connectedHeadset in connectedHeadsetList) {
                // check each headset and check if it is ACTUALLY a headset
                val majorMask = BluetoothClass.Device.Major.UNCATEGORIZED // actually want to use BITMASK but some Fwit declared it private !
                val isHeadset = (connectedHeadset.bluetoothClass?.deviceClass?.and(majorMask) == BluetoothClass.Device.Major.AUDIO_VIDEO)
                if (isHeadset) 
                    sendSpeechToSpeaker()
                }
            }
            bluetoothAdapter.closeProfileProxy(BluetoothProfile.HEADSET, proxy) // here we are finished with the proxy so clear
        }
        override fun onServiceDisconnected(profile: Int) {}
    }
```

The above listener is called in onCreate()

```
// search the list of connected bluetooth headsets
bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, btServiceListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
```

The Listener works using the Major Mask
The code for HEADSETS is (0x0400)
The Samsung Galaxy Watch is WEARABLE (0x0700)
The TicWatch Pro 3 GPS is UNCATEGORIZED (0x1F00)

For simplicity I am not showing the same code required in the BTListener to ensure if a watch disconnects it does not route audio away from the speaker !

Answer (score 0):

When I revisited this code I discovered a far simpler solution. Choose AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC in the bundle passed to the Text-to-Speech engine.

Initalisation

```
audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
ttsBundle = Bundle()
ttsBundle.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(this) { status ->
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
       Log.d(TAG, "TTS initialisation successful")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "TTS initialisation failed")
}
```

Use

```
textToSpeech.speak("Text sent to device loudspeaker or Bluetooth connected speaker", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ttsBundle, null)
```

PS I have left my first answer because I still use the code in other applications

Answer (score -1):

The above issues can be avoided by checking the audio properties directly rather than parsing each connected Bluetooth Device

```
private fun routeTTSAudioOutput() {
    // on start and when changes are detected ensure audio is being routed correctly
    val bluetoothA2DPConnected = audioOutputAvailable(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_A2DP)
    if (bluetoothA2DPConnected) {
        if (!bluetoothSCOTurnedOn) audioManager.startBluetoothSco()
        audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
    } else {
        if (bluetoothSCOTurnedOn) audioManager.stopBluetoothSco()
        audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL
    }
    audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = !bluetoothA2DPConnected
    bluetoothSCOTurnedOn = bluetoothA2DPConnected
    bundleTTS = Bundle()
    bundleTTS.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, audioManager.mode)
    this.runOnUiThread { bluetoothConnectedImageView.visibility = if (bluetoothA2DPConnected) ImageView.VISIBLE else ImageView.INVISIBLE }
}
```

The audio callback uses the above function to route text to speech

```
private val audioDeviceCallback : AudioDeviceCallback = object : AudioDeviceCallback() {
    override fun onAudioDevicesAdded(addedDevices: Array<out AudioDeviceInfo>?) {
        super.onAudioDevicesAdded(addedDevices)
        routeTTSAudioOutput()
    }
    override fun onAudioDevicesRemoved(removedDevices: Array<out AudioDeviceInfo>?) {
        super.onAudioDevicesRemoved(removedDevices)
        routeTTSAudioOutput()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the person who down voted this answer please say why. If there is another approach I would genuinely like to try it.